# Error: Uncaught (in promise) - Angular error - NullInjectorError:

Tags: angular, error-handling, module

I got this error just by placing "private homePage: HomePage" in the constructor of a component that i have.

Idk why this is hapenning

Error:

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[PaymentMethodComponent -> HomePage]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[PaymentMethodComponent -> HomePage]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HomePage!
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[PaymentMethodComponent -> HomePage]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[PaymentMethodComponent -> HomePage]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for HomePage!
    at NullInjector.get (core.js:855)
    at resolveToken (core.js:17514)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:17440)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:17266)
    at resolveToken (core.js:17514)
    at tryResolveToken (core.js:17440)
    at StaticInjector.get (core.js:17266)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (core.js:30393)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (core.js:31578)
    at resolveDep (core.js:32143)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at new ZoneAwarePromise (zone-evergreen.js:879)
    at fesm5.js:3145
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:359)
    at Object.onInvoke (core.js:39699)
    at ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone-evergreen.js:358)
    at Zone.run (zone-evergreen.js:124)
    at NgZone.run (core.js:39511)
    at AngularFrameworkDelegate.push../node_modules/@ionic/angular/dist/fesm5.js.AngularFrameworkDelegate.attachViewToDom (fesm5.js:3141)
    at attachComponent (framework-delegate-c2e2e1f4.js:3)
```

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

Have you try to do add a providers in your component.ts ?

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ],
  providers: [HomePage]
 })
```